# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ​

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

```
DROPOUT = 0.5
ACTIVATION = "tanh"

model = Sequential([    
    Dense(int(trainX.shape[1]/2), activation=ACTIVATION, input_dim=trainX.shape[1]),
    Dropout(DROPOUT),
    Dense(int(trainX.shape[1]/2), activation=ACTIVATION, input_dim=trainX.shape[1]),
    Dropout(DROPOUT),
    Dense(int(trainX.shape[1]/4), activation=ACTIVATION),
    Dropout(DROPOUT),
    Dense(100, activation=ACTIVATION),
    Dropout(DROPOUT),
    Dense(20, activation=ACTIVATION),
    Dropout(DROPOUT),
    Dense(5, activation=ACTIVATION),
    Dropout(DROPOUT),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(0.00005), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


EPOCHS = 30
BATCHSIZE = 1500


model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCHSIZE, validation_data=(validX, validY))
```

> ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: ,

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your are not converting your X or y to `numpy`.

The error springs from your data/the way you input the data. You should recheck the manner in which you feed data to your neural network as well as the type of the data (ensure that it's `numpy` array).

**Convert the Pandas Series to numpy (whether it's X or y), as the error above outlines**.

```
my_numpy_data = series.to_numpy()
#Feed this numpy data to your neural network.
```